# Nginx: private folder not accesible from web

Tags: nginx

I created a default nginx webserver in this location: `/var/www/domapi/html`

`root` in `default` is `root /var/www/domapi/html;`

I want to store certificates and other private files in a location accessible from my `$USER:www-data` that can upload, delete and create files (right permission).

Is it secure to use `/var/www/domapi/private` ?

Of course I will assign right permission for that folder `/private`.

Because I did not get any answer, I re-ask different...
With a root folder in file default as `root /var/www/domapi/html;` , is accessible from internet the folder `/var/www/domapi/private` or no? I think no but I'm looking for an expert answer.

Thank you

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html

Comment: It its'nt the answer. I don't need a private access with password or similar. I need a folder NOT accessible from web but only from webserver itself (e.g. a repository of documents to get after payment)